# Issue with compiling and running c++ program on scite

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, scite

So I'm just writing a simple c++ program and I am having some issues running the program. I could build my make file but when I try to run the testfile it gives me an `"collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"` error, `"undefined reference to Account::Account(int, double, double)"` and basically all of my methods. I've attached a picture of my .h file, and .cpp below.

[.h File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL1Ye.png)

[.cpp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjD4m.png)

And the test file is like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

Account account1(1122, 20000, 4.5);

account1.withdraw(2500);
account1.deposit(3000);

cout<<"Account Information"<<endl
<<"ID: " << account1.getID()<<endl
<<"Balance: " << account1.getBalance()<<endl
<<"Monthly Interest Rate: " << account1.getMonthlyInterestRate()<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

Make file:

```
TestAccount: TestAccount.o Account.o
    g++ TestAccount.o Account.o -o TestAccount
TestAccount.o: TestAccount.cpp Account.h
    g++ -c TestAccount.cpp
Account.o: Account.cpp Account.h
    g++ -c Account.cpp
```

Comment: *How* do you build? Can you show us the commands you execute? Or the `Makefile` that you have? Please do it by *editing your question*.

Comment: Why don't you try simply compile the whole program: g++ Account.cpp TestAccount.cpp -o TestAccount